# PHP array sort()

Tags: php, sorting

Im stuck on a sorting problem, I have an array with 10 numbers (1-10) and I need to sort the in the following way where 10 would come after 1, for example...

**desired outcome**

```
$arr['a1','a10','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9'];
```

**actual outcome**

```
$arr['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10'];

sort($arr);

$arr['a10','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9'];
```

I don't know the name of this type of sorting or how to perform it, if anyone could help me it would much appreciated.

NOTE: the numbers are part of a string

Comment: What would be the desired outcome if you add 20 and 100 to the incoming array?

Comment: What's the application of such a sort order?

Comment: @Travis I have not gotten that far as i have an array smaller than 100 but it would probably be something like 1,10,100,2,200

Comment: Can we "safely" assume that all the `string` values are actually `numbers`?

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that they are strings

Comment: Is anyone able to reproduce this? `sort` works as desired on Windows 7, PHP 5.4.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `sort($arr,SORT_STRING)` to explicitly treat the input as strings.

EDIT: Now that you've given your actual strings, try this:

```
usort($arr,function($a,$b) {
    $a = explode("=",$a);
    $b = explode("=",$b);
    return $a[0] == $b[0] ? strcmp($a[1],$b[1]) : strcmp($a[0],$b[0]);
});
```

Comment: OK I've been testing it and it doest not work with the string that I have which is `$arr = array('ASINList.ASIN.2=1580800939','ASINList.ASIN.1=1846031249 ','ASINList.ASIN.10=0340912081 ','ASINList.ASIN.3=1580800939');`

Comment: ok thanks I sorted it out, I managed to sort by keys, thanks.

Comment: Ah, well, that's because `=` > `0`, so `1=` > `10`. No wonder. Will edit with answer.

Comment: actually I would love to hear your answer

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you want to sort alphabetically, not numerically.

```
sort($arr, SORT_STRING);
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: yeah i write answers slowly so kolink probably answered as I was writing

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behaviour of sort with it's second parameter.

Try this:

```
sort($arr, SORT_STRING);
```